# Append other pdf files using gofpdf

Tags: go

We are using gofpdf to write multiple images to PDF but we would like to also be able to write other pdfs into it (append it to the document or merge it). We have a base64 of the pdf files to merge.

We can't seem to find how to do it in the docs or if it's even possible. Does anyone know how?

I tried to use RawWriteBuf or RawWriteStr using the base64, but neither seem to work.

Comment: have you attempted to use other libraries ?  a quick google of ... golang merge multiple pdf files  ... shows several repos which say they do pdf merge

Answer (score 0):

You can import pdfs with `gofpdf` using `gofpdfi`. See the discussion on github [here](https://github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf/issues/8#issuecomment-493492782). The package details on [pkg.go are here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/phpdave11/gofpdi).

An example (see [here](https://github.com/rorycl/rm2pdf/blob/master/rmpdf/pdf.go#L90) for more details):

```golang
bgpdf := gofpdi.ImportPageFromStream(pdf, sourceFH, pdfImportPage, "/MediaBox")
gofpdi.UseImportedTemplate(pdf, bgpdf, 0, 0, 210*MMtoRMPoints, 297*MMtoRMPoints)
```

In my experience `gopdfi` works great unless the PDF you are trying to import is poorly structured. I've had to pre-process some with the `pdftk` command line tool for them to work with `gofpdfi`.